# Xcode - 'openssl/opensslconf.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I want to run the openFrameworks's examples following this tutorial (http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/xcode/), but I have the following issue:

'openssl/opensslconf.h' file not found [[image]

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/xcode-7-project-generator/20144 , http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/fix-for-xcode-7-and-of-0-8-4-opensslconf-h-not-found/20800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coped from http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/fix-for-xcode-7-and-of-0-8-4-opensslconf-h-not-found/20800

> When building an OF 0.8.4 project with Xcode 7, you may see the
>   following error:
>
> > 'openssl/opensslconf.h' file not found
>
> To fix this, open the file `CoreOF.xcconfig` in
>   `libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/osx/` and add the following line
>   at the bottom:
>
> ```
> USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(OF_PATH)/libs/openssl/include"
> ```
>
> If you understand the .xcconfig format, a cleaner fix would be to
>   define a `HEADER_OPENSSL` variable at the top of the file, and add it
>   to the `OF_CORE_HEADERS` list. The above fix should work fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

This file is in /usr/include on OS X, but is not part of iOS. [As the Apple docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW9), it is possible to statically link OpenSSL into an iOS app, but they recommend using other security APIs instead.

Comment: so....which will be the solution? I've seen inside usr/include and I couldn't find the file....

Comment: /usr/include holds the header files for Mac apps, not iOS apps. The solution is to either use something other than OpenSSL, or search for "ios OpenSSL" to find projects and instructions on how to make it available for iOS.

Comment: While tballs comment is relevant for iOS, the question was about OS X openFrameworks which includes Poco that requires OpenSSL. +Jordi,  just update to 0.9 and it should be all sorted.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use the SwiftNIO library in your project and getting this error, `brew install libressl` can fix the problem.

Comment: Didn't fix for me.